# Make typescript see props from decorators

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have simple component that uses mobx and decorators like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react/native";
import { Router as ReactRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-native";
import Dashboard from "./_dashboard";
import { RouterInterface } from "../store/_router";

// -- types ----------------------------------------------------------------- //
export interface Props {
  router: RouterInterface;
}

@inject("router")
@observer
class Router extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  // -- render -------------------------------------------------------------- //
  render() {
    const { router } = this.props;
    return (
      <ReactRouter history={router.history}>
        <Switch location={router.location}>
          <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </ReactRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Router;
```

essentially `@inject("router")` adds `this.props.router` that satisfies Props interface above, however typescript doesn't account for this and whenever I use this component somewhere I get an error if I don't pass down `router` in props, hence I need to change to `router?: RouterInterface;` which is fine, but not ideal.

Is there a way to fix this issue where typescript accounts for decorators injecting the props?

Comment: IMO, there's no better way: you're using the appropriate design with TypeScript, defining the interface for the injected `props`. Since the decorator `@inject` is applied after the class definition (regarding TypeScript compilation), the class must be aware upfront of the effects of the decorator, at least regarding types.

Comment: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/256 Is a discussion about this type of problem. To summarize it: no there is currently no better way of doing it. You need to add ? to the property.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way around it.
You can declare your injected props in a separate interface and then write a getter function. I wrote about it here:
https://gist.github.com/JulianG/18af9b9ff582764a87639d61d4587da1#a-slightly-better-solution

```
interface InjectedProps {
  bananaStore: BananaStore; //  no question mark here
}

interface BananaProps {
  label: string;
}

class BananaComponent extends Component<BananaProps> {

  get injected(): InjectedProps {
    return this.props as BananaProps & InjectedProps;
  }

  render() {
    const bananas = this.injected.bananaStore.bananas; //  no exclamation mark here
    return <p>{this.props.label}:{bananas}</p>
  }

}
```